# YouTube API maxResults not getting on what number i desired using GET

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

This is the sample code on their **Try this API** web app

```
GET https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&order=date&q=nyemenzo&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

this is the sample result. I'm not getting the result per page based on my desired input

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "vkFGr4LMXYO2PcialSET3PJFLGI",
  "nextPageToken": "CAoQAA",
  "regionCode": "PH",
  "pageInfo": {
       "totalResults": 77,
       "resultsPerPage": 3
      }
}
```

Comment: make available more code you have done .

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) it seems that you're only able to set `maxResults` which defines an upper bound but not a lower one.

In essence, this makes no guarantees that the items per page are filled up to `maxResults` but only that there are not more than `maxResults`.

Instead, request the further pages using `nextPageToken` to receive the rest of the data.

---

For completeness sake, the description of the `maxResults` parameter:

> The maxResults parameter specifies the maximum number of items that should be returned in the result set. Acceptable values are 0 to 50, inclusive. The default value is 5.